# MSSQL - Dynamic selection of percentage in select statement

Tags: sql-server, dynamic

I have a process that takes a group of rows, and updates a column based on whether it's in the top 50% of rows, the middle 20% of rows, or the bottom 30% of rows.

I've done this by using the percent select as below

```
update sourcetable
set targetcolumn = a.outputdata
    from (
select top 50 percent uniqueid, outputdata
    from sourcetable a
    join Lookupstable b on a.grouptype = b.grouptype and and datacontent = 
'topbracket'
where targetcolumn is null
order by ranking desc
) a
join sourcetable b on a.uniqueid = b.uniqueid
```

I then duplicate accordingly for the middle and bottom selections. However, I have been told that these brackets may change in the future, so it would be nice to have the percentages in my lookups table and only ever need to touch that table when I'm changing the output column details or the brackets.

I have tried to declare a variable to simulate referencing of the bracket amount as below

```
declare @top int
set @top = 50 --this would be a query to look for the relevant bracket figure

select top @top percent *
    from Sourcetable
```

This does not work. Does anyone know an alternative way to dynamically select my percentage of rows from a lookup in another table?

Comment: Hi, i think you have to use dynamic SQL query and EXEC or EXECUTE todo this :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use bracket in variable.
declare @top int
set @top = 50 --this would be a query to look for the relevant bracket figure

select top (@top) percent *
    from Sourcetable

update sourcetable
set targetcolumn = a.outputdata
    from (
select top (@top) percent uniqueid, outputdata
    from sourcetable a
    join Lookupstable b on a.grouptype = b.grouptype and and datacontent = 
'topbracket'
where targetcolumn is null
order by ranking desc
) a
join sourcetable b on a.uniqueid = b.uniqueid

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. I hadn't thought of wrapping the @top in brackets. That worked a treat.

Comment: Hi Timorgano, If my answer help you then please mark it as useful.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use qynamic SQL Query using EXEC

```
declare @top  varchar(100)-- int
set @top = '50' --this would be a query to look for the relevant bracket figure
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)

set @sql = 'select top ' + @top + ' PERCENT * from Sourcetable ' 





exec (@sql)
```